# Модератор может быть и автором

Tags: дефект, правки, предлагаемые-правки

Получил уведомление о [правке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/405602) моего сообщения, там есть такой текст:

> Предложенная правка к вашему сообщению уже обработана, больше никаких действий от вас не требуется.
>
> Если вы не согласны с отклонением данной правки, её можно применить к вашему сообщению, используя кнопку «Принять» ниже.

Однако, если я нажимаю кнопку <kbd>Принять</kbd>, то вижу сообщение:

> Эта правка была отклонена ранее.
> Как модератор, вы можете пересмотреть это решение.
>
> Принять эту правку?

Было бы логично тут увидеть "как автор", а не "как модератор".

А ещё перед "Как" явно стоит лишний порбел, который стоило бы удалить.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Но ведь вы и в самом деле являетесь обладателем ромба. В чём нестыковка?

Comment: @edem он хочет остаться в истории принятия правки как автор, не как модератор :)

Comment: @PashaPash, не уверен, что где-то сохраняется подобная метка, но в целом да.